# list data from mysql with php, ajax, js

Tags: javascript, ajax

Hello friends I am creating a web application which sends data that is stored in a formula which must be called in order to multiply, but when calling the formulas and listing them it only adds one fields.
In console using console.log (data); all the data is shown but it cannot list them and doing a console.log (details); which is the variables only receives one. I don't know what the problem is, I would appreciate your help.

```
var detalles = []; 
   function agregarDetalleB(id_Dproducto,materiales,estado){
            $.ajax({
          url:"../ajax/Dproducto.php?op=buscar_DproductoB",
           method:"POST",
          data:{id_Dproducto:id_Dproducto,materiales:materiales,estado:estado},
          cache: false,
          dataType:"json",
          success:function(data){
                     
                     if(data.id_Dproducto){

            console.log(data);
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {   
            var obj = {
              Nbatida : 1,
              codDD  : id_Dproducto, 
              codDpro   : data[i].id_Mprima,
              materiales : data[i].materiales,
              unidadm  : data[i].unidadm,
              precio   : data[i].precio,
              cantidad : data[i].cantidad,
              moneda   : data[i].moneda,
              importe  : 0,
              estado   : data[i].estado
              };           
            detalles.push(obj);
             }
            console.log(detalles);
             
            listarDetallesB();
            

            $('#modalDproducto').modal("hide");
                       }
                        else {
                            bootbox.alert(data.error);
                        }       
          }  

        });  
      }
```

Comment: Your question is a bit hard to understand. But do you think that the empty loop `for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { }` could be the cause for your problem?

Comment: the loop is not working, even though the fields are inside the loop it does not list any of the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { }
                                        ^
```

you're closing the loop on the same line, thus leaving no code to loop around. You need to close the loop after you've extracted the data:

```
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {   // No } here  
        var obj = {
          Nbatida : 1,
          codDD  : id_Dproducto, 
          codDpro   : data[i].id_Mprima,
          materiales : data[i].materiales,
          unidadm  : data[i].unidadm,
          precio   : data[i].precio,
          cantidad : data[i].cantidad,
          moneda   : data[i].moneda,
          importe  : 0,
          estado   : data[i].estado
          };           
        detalles.push(obj);

        } // but here.
```

Comment: sorry friend, I already made the change thanks, but in the same way it does not go through the loop